# android:showAsAction="ifRoom" is not working when using ActiobarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have the following menu.xml structure:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_button_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/s1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_button_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/s1">
    </item>
</menu>
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater =getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }
```

If the action bar title is to long the menu items aren't hidden but the ActionBar text is made shorter.So instead ActionBarTitle i get some thing like ActionBarT... 
I tried adding android:showAsAction="ifRoom" to the items but nothing changes. How can I force the menu icons to hide if there is no space for the ActioBar title?
Thanks

Comment: You can't, sadly. That's not what `ifRoom` does.

Comment: then when to use ifRoom

Comment: `ifRoom` means place the action item on the action bar if there is space. However, space is determined by the following: less than half the width of the action bar horizontal space and the count is less than the max number of action items (varies based on smallest-width from 2 to 5).

Comment: @JakeWharton : for our app, the action bar is placing the action items properly in all devices except for the Sony Xperia E Dual, where ALL items are always shown taking the whole space of the action bar and the titles appear like this: A... Also, much more than the half of the horizontal space... any idea why?

Comment: I haven't used the device. If it runs Android 4.0 or higher it's a very real possibility that they changed the action bar behavior.